# How to force a function to pass a certain object (e.g. value) instead of failing and passing an error message

Tags: r, error-handling

Is there a way to force the function to pass a value (e.g. 0) instead of failing and passing an error message to the screen?
The reason for asking is that I try to include an lme function(nlme) in an aggregate (stats) of a table but the lme function sends an error message in certain cases and the aggregate call fails. 
example of the error message and the situation that cause it.

```
ID= c("3", "15", "24", "25", "26", "28", "29", "30")
    value= c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
    fit = lme(value ~ 1, random = ~ 1 | ID)
    Error in chol.default((value + t(value))/2) : 
      the leading minor of order 1 is not positive definite
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`?try` and/or `?tryCatch` are your friends (they may even be documented on the same page).

I usually use an idiom like

```
ncoefs <- 5
fit <- lme(...)
if (inherits(fit,"try-error")) rep(NA,ncoefs) else fixef(fit)
```

(`inherits()` is more general than `if class()==...` because `class()` can return a vector of characters with length > 1 ...)

Comment: Thanks! I made the code work after your original comment, and now return to see your answer. I'll need to take some time to study all these unfamiliar functions you include in your answer.